# How to disable selected value in other chosen select & close selected option in single chosen select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-chosen

I'm using Chosen select Version 1.8.7, I've got 3 Chosen selects side by side, it pull the options from the database table.

If I select option 1 in the first Chosen select then that option should be disabled in second and third Chosen select, if I select option 2 in the second Chosen select then that value should be disabled in the first and third Chosen select, if I select option 3 in the third chosen select then it should be disabled in the first and second Chosen select.

Also I want to remove the selected option from Chosen select, like multi-select, but i want to use single select only. I didn't find this in the documentation of Chosen select.

Here is my code:

[Check fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deqngcmz/6/)

```
<select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" tabindex="1">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="United States">United States</option>
  <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
  <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
  <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
</select>
<select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" tabindex="2">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="United States">United States</option>
  <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
  <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
  <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
</select>
<select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" tabindex="3">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="United States">United States</option>
  <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
  <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
  <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
</select>
```

```js
//This makes chosen select the first matching result from the list
//if you wrote anything on the input element (and it matches
//anything). 
$('select').chosen();

$container1 = $('#select1').next();
$('input', $container1).change(function() {
  var value = $('.active-result:first', $container1).text();
  if (value !== undefined) {
    $('#select1').data('chosen').result_select(value);
  }
});

//Alternatively you could achieve the same with something like
//this, but it's getting a bit complicated:
var $container2 = $('#select2').next();
$('input', $container2).change(function() {
  var option_index = $('.chosen-container .active-result:first').data("option-array-index");
  if (option_index !== undefined) {
    var option_value = $('#select2 option:nth-child(' + (option_index + 1) + ')').val();
    $('#select2').val(option_value);
    $('#select2').trigger("chosen:updated");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

select {
  width: 200px;
}

tr>td:first-child {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 7px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="select1">Using Chosen#result_select method</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="select1" class="first" multiple>
        <option value="1">abc</option>
        <option value="2">def</option>
        <option value="3">ghi</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="select2">Using other means...</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="select2" class="second" multiple>
        <option value="1">abc</option>
        <option value="2">def</option>
        <option value="3">ghi</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I've got the solution on close selected option, now i want disable selected option in other select

Comment: I've update my fiddle, it working for deselect option , i tried for disable selected options, but it wont work pls check this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/deqngcmz/7/

Comment: You could have an onchange event listener function gather the selected value of each select. Then you have various methods to *remove* that same value from the other selects. You could use the jQuery `.css()` function to hide the repeated `<option>`. Just remember to reverse that in the de-select function.

Comment: When i use bootstrap it wont work, can anybody let me know what is the mistake in my code. Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/j14cfvt0/3/

Comment: I would suggest opening a new question instead of necroing this one. @Jon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<form>
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    <div class="side-by-side clearfix">
    <select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." id="1" class="chosen-select" tabindex="1">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="United States">United States</option>
                <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
                <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
                <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
                <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
     </select>
     <select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." id="2" class="chosen-select" tabindex="2">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="United States">United States</option>
                <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
                <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
                <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
                <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
     </select>
     <select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." id="3" class="chosen-select" tabindex="3">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="United States">United States</option>
                <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
                <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
                <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
                <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
    </select>
    <select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." id="4" class="chosen-select" tabindex="4">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="United States">United States</option>
                <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
                <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
                <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
                <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
    </select>
    <select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." id="5" class="chosen-select" tabindex="5">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="United States">United States</option>
                <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
                <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
                <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
                <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
    </select>
    <select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." id="6" class="chosen-select" tabindex="6">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="United States">United States</option>
                <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
                <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
                <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
                <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
    </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/docsupport/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/docsupport/prism.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/docsupport/init.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</form>
<script>
var selected=[];
$.each($('.chosen-select'), function(){
    selected[$(this).attr('id')] = '';
});

$('.chosen-select').change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(selected[$(this).attr('id')] !== ''){
        var oldValue = selected[$(this).attr('id')];
        $(this).siblings('.chosen-select').addBack().children('option').each(function() {
            if($(this).val() === oldValue)
                $(this).removeAttr('disabled').trigger('chosen:updated');
        });        
    }
    selected[$(this).attr('id')] = value;
    $(this).siblings('.chosen-select').addBack().children('option').each(function() {
        if($(this).val() === value)
            $(this).attr('disabled', true).trigger('chosen:updated');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: i got the solution for remove selected option, now i want to achive if option is selected then that option is disabled in all dropdowns.
check my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/deqngcmz/7/

Comment: dint get you, pls explain

Comment: I updated script. Both, vanilla JS and jQuery do disable selected value. Stored result is different: js version gives mixed array with each Select with its selected values, jQuery version is from your Fiddle script and selected values are just pushed into array.

Comment: Somehow I managed to miss the fact that question is about Chosen. (I blame age... or bad weather or something :) ) Sorry 'bout that. I changed the script accordingly.

Comment: its working now, but when i change option it should be enable again that is not working

Comment: added .siblings().removeAttr('disabled');

Comment: pls check still not working properly, it removes disabled attribute but it enables same value in all dropdowns
http://jsfiddle.net/deqngcmz/11/

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you found out the option to remove the already selected value, I only worked on how you could *"remove"*, or in this case, *"disable"*, the selected value from one select in the other selects.

Note that this example uses jQuery, and one would therefore have to include a jQuery library for this to work.

What you can do is have an event listener that triggers *onchange* on your drop-down elements. You can then check on what has been selected, what the previous selects were, and if other selects outside of those has been made.

You then set the attribute *disabled* on your value in the other selects, by looking at what was previously selected. If they match, then they become disabled. However, if they don't, then you remove the *disabled* attribute again so that you can keep alternating between your selections.

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".chosen-select").change(function () {
        var value = $(this);
        var prevVal = value.data("prev");
        var otherSelects = $(".chosen-select").not(this);
        otherSelects.find('option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').attr('disabled', true);
        if (prevVal) {
            otherSelects.find('option[value="' + prevVal + '"]').attr('disabled', false);
        }
        value.data("prev", value.val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" tabindex="1">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="United States">United States</option>
  <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
  <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
  <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
</select>
<select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" tabindex="2">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="United States">United States</option>
  <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
  <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
  <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
</select>
<select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" tabindex="3">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="United States">United States</option>
  <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
  <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
  <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I'm using chosen select, i dint fond any solution on disable selected fields in all other drop downs & unfortunately your code also not supports chosen select.

Comment: Can't you include this as normal JS inside your relevant document? Is it overwritten by your *chosen-select* library?

Comment: No, it can't coz chosen select structure is different than normal select
<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single" title="" style="width: 20%;"><a class="chosen-single chosen-single-with-deselect"> <span>United States</span><abbr class="search-choice-close"></abbr> </a> <div class="chosen-drop"><div class="chosen-search"><input class="chosen-search-input" type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="1"> </div><ul class="chosen-results"><li class="active-result result-selected" data-option-array-index="1">United States</li> </ul> </div> </div>

Comment: You should add the relevant structure to your question, as it is highly relevant for a proper solution. People will use whatever angle they get from the code in your current question. You can still use the same approach as I have in this answer, you would just have to alter it a bit to fit the logic, the approach is the same. A the moment you're basically doing this: http://xyproblem.info/ . People will provide solutions to the current selects presented in your question, but that is actually not what you need at the end of the day, so add the relevant code.

Comment: chosen run-time create this structure.
We use this code only <select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" tabindex="2"> <option value=""></option><option value="United States">United States</option></select>

Comment: Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/deqngcmz/6/, this having relevant code only, as i said earlier chosen create above structure at run-time